# Quill editor html class not able to style in email body

Tags: css, angular, quill, ngx-quill

am using angular 10 and included ngx quill editor to show the rich text editor.
when we save the html content into database, it saves with html class type like below:

```
<li class="ql-indent-2">lbmlkfdnblblfdsb</li>
```

and when we send an email through our app, we send the above content in the email body but the css class won't available.so it is not displaying the style.
How can we achieve this in Angular ?

I tried below code and didnt get any luck :

https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/1451

```
<quill-editor #body name="body" id="body" [(ngModel)]="studyNotification.messageText" (onSelectionChanged)="editorSelectionChanged($event)"
        (onEditorCreated)="editorCreated($event)" [style]="{height: '250px', background: 'white'}">
       
         <div id="toolbar-container"  quill-editor-toolbar>                
            <!-- Text Size  -->
           <span class="ql-formats">
             <select class="ql-font"></select>
             <select class="ql-size"></select>
           </span>
           <!-- Text Formatting  -->
           <span class="ql-formats">
             <button class="ql-bold"></button>
             <button class="ql-italic"></button>
             <button class="ql-underline"></button>
             <button class="ql-strike"></button>
           </span>
           <span class="ql-formats">
             <select class="ql-color"></select>
             <select class="ql-background"></select>
           </span>
             <!-- Subscript/superscript  -->
           <span class="ql-formats">
             <button class="ql-script" value="sub"></button>
             <button class="ql-script" value="super"></button>
           </span>
           <!-- Text Block format -->
              <!-- Header Sizes  -->
           <span class="ql-formats">
             <button class="ql-header" value="1"></button>
             <button class="ql-header" value="2"></button>
             <!-- <button class="ql-blockquote"></button>
             <button class="ql-code-block"></button> -->
           </span>
            <!-- Ordered List / Bullets   -->
             <!--  Indenting -->
           <span class="ql-formats">
             <button class="ql-list" value="ordered"></button>
             <!-- <button class="ql-list" value="bullet"></button> -->
             <button class="ql-indent" value="-1"></button>
             <button class="ql-indent" value="+1"></button>
           </span>
          <span class="ql-formats">
            <!--   <button class="ql-direction" value="rtl"></button> -->
             <select class="ql-align"></select>
           </span>
           <span class="ql-formats">
             <button class="ql-link"></button>
             <button class="ql-image"></button>
             <button class="ql-video"></button>
             <!-- <button class="ql-formula"></button> -->
           </span>
           <!-- <span class="ql-formats">
             <button class="ql-clean"></button>
           </span> -->
         </div>
      
       </quill-editor>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Override toolbar?

Comment: i want to bind whatever the text inside the editor into a ngModel with instyle css instead of quill class

Comment: <li class="ql-indent-2">lbmlkfdnblblfdsb</li> want toconvert something like
<li style= "padding or someother dynamic style">lbmlkfdnblblfdsb</li>

Comment: Would a solution where the already existing ql- styles are applied to the email work for you? You can paste the core quill css styles in a style tag in your email template. You may have some conflicts with styles already in the template and will need to add or remove the ql-editor class, but this does work for me in my email templates.  If this is a workable solution for you let me know and I can give a few more details on it. It's pretty straightforward though.

Comment: @BootDev Not sure what we did later on this work since it was a lower priority but there was this css not able to  recognize since it css are in different place